# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for multiple elements in servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to create Spring Hibernate Maven project.

I'm following [given](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-orm/spring-hibernate-integration-example/) example in howtodoinjava.com

While I'm trying to run the project I keep getting multiple xml validation errors in my ***employee-servlet.xml*** file.


**cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'. [18] 


cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'. [19] 


cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'. [61]**

Given below is my employee-servlet.xml file.

Please help me to figure out what is missing here.

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.employee.controller" />
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
        </property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}">
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.employee.service.EmployeeServiceImpl"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thank you.

EDIT: My project Sturcture. 
[image]

EDIT : My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>employee</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employee</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <!-- JBoss repository for Hibernate -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
            Core utilities used by other modules.
            Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
            Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
            Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
            Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
            This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
            Define this if you need any of these integrations
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
            Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
            (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
            Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
            Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
            (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
            Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
            Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
            Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
            This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>  
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>  
            <version>1.2.15</version>  
            <exclusions>  
                <exclusion>  
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>  
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>  
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>  
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>  
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>  
                </exclusion>  
                <exclusion>  
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>  
                </exclusion>  
            </exclusions>  
            <scope>runtime</scope>  
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>employee</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Post your pom.xml also

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam done. please check

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `xsi:schemaLocation` you have trailing `/` for all the schema except for beans. remove the trailing `/` and it will solve the issue.

For Example the schema for context is

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

it should be

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

So your XML should be as follows.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.employee.controller" />
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
        </property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}">
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.employee.service.EmployeeServiceImpl"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Any chance that you know some good tutorials about this that I can follow?

Comment: @pippilongstocking https://www.mkyong.com/all-tutorials-on-mkyong-com/ check this